# First person movement tracking using simple camera

Tags: algorithm, tracking, motion

The situation: I need to be able to track a hovering drone's translation (not height) and rotation over the ground using a downwards facing camera. I wouldn't know where to start looking. Can anyone with experience point me to some theory or resources? I'm looking for the type of algorithms a mouse would use but am not having much luck so far. Most results detail tracking an object in a fixed frame. In my case the environment is relatively static and the camera moves.

Comment: Real time or post processing of a recorded video?

Comment: @mako-taco Real time.